# CRM 2011 workflow size limitations

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Are there any limitations on how "big" a CRM workflow can be?
I have a workflow which has about 30 steps and it brings the worflow designer to crawl.
It takes 2+ minutes to load the designer web page and performing any design activities such as adding a new step and selecting a new entity for a create/update operation and selecting "Set properties" and saving takes approx 2+ minutes each. Activating/Deactivating the workflow takes a long time as well.
Any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: I was looking with Fiddler, and for a relatively simple workflow, trying to add a 'create' step (task) was using a ton of bandwidth.  Compressed it was 140k bytes.  Uncompressed it was > 2MB.  Most likely your problem is either massive bandwidth the larger the workflow gets (more steps to expose) and/or the massive document which makes up that bandwidth.

Comment: Interesting. You'd think MSFT would have caught this unless every one is just implementing small and simple workflows.

Comment: Yea... MSCRM seems to show its weaknesses under heavy customization.  I suppose the idea of child workflows may help you... if you don't need backwards references to earlier steps in the workflow.  Not quite like Arabela says with having one parent calling 10 child workflows but having A call B, B call C, C call D (etc) so everything executes in order.  Probably too limiting to actually be useful... Good luck friend.

Comment: Not sure if it'd help you but have you considered coding the work flows using C# and WWF instead of the GUI wizard? There are some drawbacks, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use child workflows (`Start child workflow` step) and call them in one parent workflow.

It would be more easy (and maintainable) to change the workflow definition. When you publish the workflow, he gets compiled and this is the reason it takes so much.

From a performance point a view i think that the long workflow performs better. I don't know your specific constraints but this could be an approach to make the changes on your workflow easier.

Comment: The issue is at design time not run time.